# Where is this setproperty method,used in below statement defined which is used to invoke IE and chrome browsers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Where is this setproperty  method,used in below statement defined which is used to invoke IE and chrome browsers?

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E://chromedriver.exe");

Comment: Did you done your own [research](https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/tag/system-setproperty)?

Comment: I could find same general info everywhere but not quite answer to my doubt .My actual doubt is whether the System property "webdriver.chrome.driver" was existing in OS or added later due to Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Actually setProperty is used to set environment variable on the OS level, which is why it is invoked by calling System.setProperty.

By defining it that way, then you could use webdriver to spawn instance of Chromedriver

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver()
driver.get(url)
```

There are other ways to set this up depends on the requirement, it is pretty clear defined in https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

Comment: My actual doubt is whether the property -webdriver.chrome.driver is already existing or modified later and at what time?

Comment: the property should be set when you want to initialize webdriver class, so it the first thing to do before instantiate webdriver class. it is not there by default, you should set it manually. The other way is to make sure chromedrive/iedriver callable in command prompt/console, this is could be done by setting the driver in the os PATH envar, so you don't have to define the property in the code

Comment: additional information, if you call System.setProperty means you define that variable with specific name has specified value. The name webdriver.chrome.driver, is the variable name needed by selenium. So then we add it using setProperty, so it's not there by default. I think your question more to understanding what is environment variable more than selenium